# cocos2d-x How To Use External Instances?

Tags: cocos2d-x

As mentioned on the title, I'm trying to use an instance out of its function.

There is a spr sprite instance in the Helloworld::init()
I want to use it inside the HelloWorld::menuCallback1(Ref* sender)
so once the menu is clicked, the instance spr will rotate.

Help me please!!!

```
void HelloWorld::menuCallback1(Ref* sender) {
    auto item = (MenuItemFont*)sender;

    auto actionRotation = RotateBy::create(3.0, 1080);
    spr->runAction(actionRotation);
}

bool HelloWorld::init() {
    if (!Layer::init()) return false;

    Size winSize = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();

    auto spr = Sprite::create("ch.png");
    spr->setPosition(Point(winSize.width / 2, 70));
    spr->setAnchorPoint(Point(0.5, 0));
    this->addChild(spr);

    // 메뉴(Menu)
    auto item_1 = MenuItemFont::create("MOVE UP RIGHT", CC_CALLBACK_0(HelloWorld::menuCallback1, this));
    auto menu = Menu::create(item_1, NULL);
    menu->alignItemsVertically();
    this->addChild(menu);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation menuCallback looks like this:

```
typedef std::function<void(Ref*)> ccMenuCallback;
```

So it doesn't have any params.

But you have 2 other ways to achieve that:

1) make Sprite* spr instance in .h file,

2) use item_1->setUserObject(spr) and extract it in menuCallback1 function using item->getUserObject.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass in a lambda for any callbacks in cocos2d-x:

```
[&](Ref* const ref){menuCallback1(ref);}
```